# How do quickly locate an open word document in the finder?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, finder

I am trying to find a way to quickly locate the current word file I am working on in the finder on macOS. I used to use the following method, but due to an update in word it no longer works...

Example: I have a movie file open in quicktime. To access the file in the finder, I can 'ctrl click' the filename in the middle top of the window and use the dropdown menu to open the enclosing folder. This is a very fast and simple method for accessing the file.

This method works on most Mac applications - and used to work on Microsoft Word until a recent update. I can use spotlight to find the file, but this involves typing out the file name and searching through potential duplicates. I already have the file open and simply need to locate it in the finder.

Comment: Which version of Word are you using? This still works for me with v16.63.1.

Comment: I'm on version 16.60 - using MS365